# How to find the last listing of installed application thru APT

Tags: 11.04, installation

How to find the last listing of installed application on ubuntu.  Is there any way to find thru APT.

I see that command

```
"last" - used to listing of last logged users.
```

Is there any similar tool for last installed application listing on ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain this information from `dpkg` log files:

```
less $(ls -rt /var/log/dpkg.log*) |
    awk '$3 ~ /^(install|upgrade|remove|purge)$/'
```